# Log4j configuration in Grails production environment with grails.config.locations

Tags: grails, log4j

I am  trying to maintain the log4j configuration in a separate file in production environment. I have this `log4j.properties` file (which in production resides in `WEB-INF/classes`):

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout
log4j.rootLogger.additivity=false
log4j.logger.grails.app=info, stdout
log4j.additivity.grails.app=false
log4j.additivity.grails.app.service=false
log4j.logger.grails.app.controller=debug, stdout
log4j.additivity.grails.app.controller=false
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%7r] %6p - %14.14c - %m%n
```

I completely removed the log4j configuration from the `Config.groovy`. And according to the second option in this comment http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-2730?focusedCommentId=137021&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#action_137021 I added the location of `log4j.properties` in `Config.groovy` this way:

```
  production {
    grails.serverURL = "http://xxxxx.ru/${appName}"
    grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:log4j.properties" ]
  }
```

But when deploying the application I still get the exception about the `stacktrace.log` file:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: stacktrace.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:207)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
...
```

I do not understand why.. Anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: stacktrace.log (Permission denied)
```

should mean that the user that Tomcat is running under does not have proper write permissions in the folder where Log4J tries to create the *stacktrace.log* file. By default, [this is the folder](http://www.pubbs.net/201005/grails/39786-re-grails-user-configuring-stacktrace-log-running-packed-war-in-tomcat.html) that had been the working directory when Tomcat had been started.

You can specify a custom *stacktrace.log* location with the `log4j.appender.stacktraces.File` configuration option, [like so](http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html):

```
log4j.logger.stacktraces.com.foo=INFO,stacktraces
log4j.additivity.stacktraces=false
log4j.appender.stacktraces=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stacktraces.File=${log.dir}/fooStacktraces.log
log4j.appender.stacktraces.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.daily}
log4j.appender.stacktraces.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stacktraces.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}}%p%m%n
```

Comment: I have taken your configuration, changed it a little:

log4j.logger.stacktraces=INFO,stacktraces
log4j.additivity.stacktraces=false
log4j.appender.stacktraces=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stacktraces.File=/var/log/tomcat6/fooStacktraces.log
log4j.appender.stacktraces.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.stacktraces.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stacktraces.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS/zzz}%p%m%n

Comment: After this `fooStacktraces.log` is really created. BUT I figured out that my webapp still tries to create `stracktraces.log` in the CATALINA_BASE directory. I don't understand why this happens. In my mind the whole point of the `grails.config.locations` property is to *carry log4j configuration completely out* of the `Config.groovy`. But still my app tries tries to create its own `stacktraces.log`. It turns out that I made my new configuration but did not turn off the default one. Why?

Comment: Sorry, the log4j conf is not formatted well here in the comments.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. - You may try to [disable the stacktrace log in Config.groovy][1]. 

  [1]: http://info.michael-simons.eu/2009/03/24/grails-completely-disable-stacktracelog-file/ (aren't links working in comments?)

Answer (score 1):

By default, *properties* files (like any other resources that are not compiled) are *not* copied to the *WEB-INF/classes* folder.

To copy them, manually, create the file *scripts/Events.groovy* in your project and add the following code (assuming that your *properties* file is in the application root):

```
eventCompileEnd = {
    ant.copy(todir:classesDirPath) {
        fileset(file:"${basedir}/*.properties")
    }
}
```

Comment: But my deployed WAR - I mean the webapp, deployed from the WAR made by `grails war` - HAS the file `log4j.properties` in `WEB-INF/classes`.